# Using inner join between 2 tables, For multiple records wrt 1 particular column, sum integer columns, make varchar columns comma separated

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am working on 2 tables.

Below is the structure -

```
MainComponents (ComponentNo varchar(255), description varchar(255),cost float, Age int);
RevisedComponents(ComponentNo varchar(255), description varchar(255), cost float, Age int);
```

Both tables can have multiple values for componentNo column.
So, if I do inner join, I can get multiple rows for each componentNo.

I am trying to get only 1 row for each ComponentNo, description column should be comma separated(in case values are different), cost column should be summed up, Age will be same for all rows,so select any row value.

Sample output data -

```
ComponentNo - AHGHGHHHK

Description - HW,SW

Cost - 100(50+50)
Age - 10
```

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide sample data for MainComponents and RevisedComponents. Make sure it'll match your sample output.

Comment: Hi Felix, MainComponent(AHGHGHHK, HW, 50, 10), RevisedComponents(AHGHGHHK, HW,50,10)(AHGHGHHK, SW, 50, 10).I have assumed I will get rows for this component - AHGHGHHK using inner join

Comment: Hi Felix, suppose I have 3 records. Description includes - hw,hw,sw. How can i make sure that hw appear only once. Please help

Answer (score 0):

First, do a `JOIN` on both tables. To get the `Cost`, use `SUM`. To get the `Age`, you can use either `MIN` or `MAX`. Then use `FOR XML PATH` to concatenate the `Description`:

```
SELECT
    mc.ComponentNo,
    x.Description,
    Cost = SUM(rc.Cost),
    Age = MIN(rc.Age)
FROM MainComponents mc
INNER JOIN RevisedComponents rc
    ON rc.ComponentNo = mc.ComponentNo
CROSS APPLY(
    SELECT STUFF((
        SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + description
        FROM RevisedComponents
        WHERE ComponentNo = mc.ComponentNo
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ), 1, 2, '') AS Description
)x
GROUP BY mc.ComponentNo, x.Description
```

Comment: Thanks Felix, let me try this and revert. Thanks much

Comment: Hi Felix, suppose I have 3 records. Description includes - hw,hw,sw. How can i make sure that hw appear only once. Please help

Comment: Just add a `DISTINCT` inside the `STUFF`. `SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + description...`

Comment: @SG_ Then please accept the answer so that this question will be resolved.